# Chrome Extrensions Share Script variables

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, manifest.json

I am working on a chrome extension that has 2 script files. One is attached to the `manifest.json` as `content_scripts`(page script). And I also have a script file attached to my add-on `popup.html` file(add-on script).

When I declare a `var` in my page script then I try calling it in my add-on script and I get `undeclared varible`.

Can can I get communications between the two scripts?
Because if I try doing it all in one then it can not access the elements of the opposite page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily pass values from background to content script using [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Se below a simple example:

> manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Test ",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Test "
  },
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "tabs"
  ], "content_scripts" : [{
            "matches" :  ["*://*/*"],
            "js" : ["content.js"]
        }]
}
```

> background.js

```
  chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(){
       chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {data: "some value"});
        });
    });
```

> content.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(handleMessage);
function handleMessage(request) {
    console.log(request.data);
}
```

Comment: This method isn't working for me. Why are you checking the tab and window? Does it matter? I just need my variables to be accessible in both scripts

Comment: Content script and popup.html script both works in different contexts therefore variables of each other can't be accessible for both. Only way is to communicate each other using messaging. Checking tab and window will ensure that the communication is being done in the current active tab. Hope this is clear now.